# Invert text layer used as clipping mask? (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I have three layers; a canvas b/w background, a text layer, and an image (bottom to top). I set the text as a clipping mask for the image, so you get the background, the text, and the image can be seen through the gaps in the text. The only problem in the font I'm using covers more of the image than it shows, and I was wondering how I could invert what parts of the font cover the image and which parts show it?

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: I think it might be easier to help with this issue if you uploaded the image you're working on. Reading your description, I think you might just be able to use a layer mask and then black out or show part of the text layer.

Comment: Here is an image of what I have: http://imgur.com/pPMJeJh

Comment: I want the bits of the text that cover the image to reveal it, and vice versa, i.e invert what the text is covering/showing

Comment: Well the image is only going to show up where there is text. So you're saying that not enough of the image is showing. Well you can't make more of the image show where there isn't text. You can either find a thicker font version, use a different font or make a copy of the image and manually show parts of it with a layer mask.

Answer (score 1):

Select your text layer. Using the Magic Wand tool hold shift and click in areas you'd like to add to the Clipping Mask. With all the areas selected go to Select > Expand Selection > 1px. Create a new layer, fill this selection on the new layer. Select this layer and the text layer and group them (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) then select the picture on top of it and you can create a **clipping mask onto the entire group**:

[image: Clipping to Group]

*And for anyone interested the font is Sullivan by Jason Mark Jones available here: http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=sullivan*

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you mean, you set the mask and some parts of the top image doesn't show up in the text while some parts( you don't want to show) show up.
Well, if that is your question, you can **click** on **image layer** then activate **Move tool**  (press V from keyboard) and move the image as you like. Show the parts you wants and hide others.

Answer (score -1):

The following procedure will help you to show more part of the image through the text.

> 1.Create a *New_layer* over the *text_layer*
>
> 2.Use any brush with 100% hardness and 100% opacity to paint over the gaps in the *text_layer* where you actually what the image to be shown.
>
> ( Use a any solid color to paint over )
>
> 3.Group the *New_layer* & *text_layer* together.
>
> 4.Merge the Group.
>
> 5.Use the "Merged layer " as a clipping mask for the image.
>
> 6.Now you can see more part of the image is visible through the text.
>
> 7.If you need to add more image , simply paint with the same brush used above in the *Merged layer clipping mask*

Comment: Why are you merging the group? Or using a brush for this?